# is the "is" operator just syntactic sugar for the "IsInstanceOfType" method

Tags: c#, types, keyword, isinstance

Are the following code snippets equivalent?

```
class a
{}

class b:a
{}

b foo=new b();
```

//here it comes

```
foo is a
```

//...is the same as...

```
typeof(a).isinstanceoftype(foo)
```

Or maybe one of the other Type Methods map closer to the is operator.
e.g. "IsAssignableFrom" or "IsSubclassOf"

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251310/why-is-is-implemented-as-as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not. In fact, if you peek into `IsInstanceOfType` you will see that the very first code line actually performs a comparison using `is`, which would effectively lead to a `StackOverflowException` if that was the case.

The `is` operator leads to an [`isinst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx) operation in the IL code.

Comment: it seems so that the implementation of IsInstanceOfType got a lot simpler in .Net 4.0. It basically just delegates to IsAssignableFrom.

Answer (score 6):

It isn't, because `is` is tolerant to null reference at the left-hand side.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the same as `is` is translated into the [isinst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst.aspx) opcode whereas `IsInstanceOf` is a normal virtual call on `Type`.